# How to know when a widget from CARTO Airship is loaded

Tags: carto, carto-vl, airship

I'm getting some information from a server using *fetch* and using jQuery *append* to dinamically add the widgets to my page, but I need to know when the widget is done loading, there's any trigger that shows me that the widget is already loaded? here's my piece of code

```
  function drawLayers(sqlSource, style, ctrl, id_layer, widgetsObj, visibility){
    fetch(sqlSource)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data){
    source[ctrl] = new carto.source.GeoJSON(data);
    vizLayer[ctrl] = new carto.Layer('layer', source[ctrl], style);
    vizLayer[ctrl].id = id_layer;

    layerBridge[ctrl] = new AsBridge.VLBridge({
      carto: carto,
      map: map,
      layer: vizLayer[ctrl],
      source: source[ctrl]
    });
    drawWidgets(widgetsObj, vizLayer[ctrl], layerBridge[ctrl]);
    vizLayer[ctrl].addTo(map, 'watername_ocean');
    if(!visibility){
      vizLayer[ctrl].hide();
    }



    layerBridge[ctrl].build();



 });
}




function drawWidgets(widgetsObj, vizLay, bridgeCtrl){
  for(var i = 0; i<widgetsObj.length;i++){
    if(vizLay.id == widgetsObj[i].source.id){
      if(widgetsObj[i].type == 'category'){
        $('.as-sidebar--right').append('<div class="as-box '+widgetsObj[i].source.id+'"><as-category-widget visible-categories="5" show-clear heading='+widgetsObj[i].title+'  id='+widgetsObj[i].options.column+'></as-category-widget></div>');
    bridgeCtrl.category('#'+widgetsObj[i].options.column, widgetsObj[i].options.column, {
      readOnly: false
    });
    vizmod = new carto.Viz('@widgets: viewportFeatures($'+widgetsObj[i].options.column+')');
    vizLay.blendToViz(vizmod);

    }
```

I need to use jquery to mod some properties from the widget after is loaded, I've tried to use the code below, just for an example, but it doesn't work

```
$('#'+widgetsObj[i].options.column).on('loaded', example_function);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the properties of the widget right after the append call. For instance, you could change `visibleCategories` and it should work. If you need to read the properties back, you have to wait until the next tick.

From a VL <--> Airship perspective, the widget will update on every `update` event on the layer it's bridged to. You could listen to that event and then do whatever changes you require to the properties.

However, keep in mind that [certain properties](https://carto.com/developers/airship/reference/#/bridge/vl/category?a=widget-side-effects) of the widget are updated by the bridge, so you changes might get overwritten on the next `update` event.

It might be interesting adding a callback that fires each time the widget is updated, I will open an issue for it.